# C++ Builder - CodeGuard and madExcept

Tags: c++builder-10.2-tokyo, rad-studio, codeguard

I like to use Codeguard utility to detecting array range and memory leaks. Unfortunately, cg doesn’t work in RAD studio 10.2 for me (we have an installation of 10.2 on three computers and same problems). When CG detect problem in code it freezes and no line highlight in debugger. In cgl file there is nothing or one or two lines of text – no more. This was tested on small VCL project with one main cpp file. **Does anybody know what can be configured to solve this problem?** On older version XE7 there is no problem with CG and I was widely use this.
So, I am trying madExcept. Can madExcept detect array overrun problem like this:

int array[10];
array[10]=0;

For me with default configuration nothing is happen when code steps on array[10]=0 (but CG in previous version of rad can detect like problem). And when program is finished madExcept says: no leak detection. **Can madExcept detects this kind of overruns or not?**

Comment: CodeGuard is a POS that has never worked properly, I have NEVER had success using it.

Comment: For my point of view the CG works very well. Iam using it to detect buffers overrun and memory leaks and it is really good . I have suspicion that cg doesn’t work under WIN 10 in RAD Studio 10.2. Under WIN 7 in 10.2 works. Does cg have problems with WIN 10, is it true?

I tested madExcept and it doesn’t work for my bigger project around 400files. CG yes. In testing project with one file madExcept works good and sufficiently for me.

So, what utility is good for this job? Another one? What  embarcadero means?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to MadExcept might be EurekaLog, but I can't tell, as I use MadExcept in Delphi which works for me.